# is it possible to get the latest version numbers for multiple modules at once from npm?

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I can't find this anywhere on npm's docs or SO, but ideally I'd like to pull down metadata for a list of packages owned by a given user, then I could extract the version numbers from those packages, or any other metadata I needed.

To explain use case briefly, I'm using Grunt.js to build documentation for 40+ repos, and the docs are not usually in the same repo as the project being documented, so I've been using various methods for keeping version numbers and other metadata up-to-date. Any suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [matchdep](http://npmjs.org/matchdep) and [latest](http://npmjs.org/latest):

```
var latest = require('latest');
var matchdep = require('matchdep');
matchdep.filter('*').forEach(function(dep) {
  latest(dep, function(err, version) {
    console.log(dep, version);
  });
});
```

Comment: Great idea! I've seen those used but it didn't even occur to me,   thanks!